# Parse Custom DateTime

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble parsing this datetime:

```
        DateTime ParseDateTime(string dateString)
        {
            //dateString is "2011-07-22 16:11:14,770"
            var format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss,fff";
            var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return dateTime;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `@` in `format` variable? You meant `@"..."` ?

Comment: works for me with the sample provided.

Comment: The issue was it was twenty four hour time so it needed to be HH instead of hh

Comment: For your provided sample Darin's answer is correct though...

Answer (score 4):

I guess the superfluous `@` in the beginning of your format is wrong. So:

```
var format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss,fff";
```

You were probably confused by a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx) which is what `@` represents.

For example the following works perfectly fine:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss,fff";
        var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("2011-07-25 11:10:17,328", format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: String not recognized as a valid DateTime exception

Comment: @Robert, so your string doesn't equal what you said it does in your question. What is it actual value? As you can see in my updated answer if the value is `2011-07-25 11:10:17,328`, the `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss,fff` parse format will work fine with `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: The issue was it was supposed to be HH not hh since it was 24 hour time

Comment: @Robert, oops, indeed. HH is for 24 hour format. But the @ string literal you put in the beginning was also wrong.